# How to export/import the product "Tax Code" in Orocommcerce?

Tags: orocommerce

How can I export/import the Product>"Tax Code"-Attribute?
I tried the same as with "brands" described here:
https://forum.oroinc.com/orocommerce/topic/how-import-products-with-brands/
This worked for "Brands", but the "Tax Code" Entity is still missing in the export data.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable TaxCode import/export from the entity "product".

Entity Manager > Product > field "taxCode" > set"Exclude Columns" to "No"

TaxCode should now be listed in your import template.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).